# Magento Cron job working - AOE Scheduler no heartbeat

Tags: magento, cron

I am using my dev site to test an abandoned cart email through MageMonkey/Mandrill. I believe I already have the cron job already configured as other transactional emails send without a problem (maybe this assumption is wrong?).

I also installed the AOE Scheduler and it displays all of the correct cron jobs. After I manually run the heartbeat and generate a schedule - nothing else runs and I get the notice that the "heartbeat is older than xx minutes."

I'm honestly not sure where my issue is - whether it is because I am in the dev site (shouldn't be because other emails send), the cron job configuration or the AOE Scheduler, etc.

In my magento admin under configuration I have the following:
generate schedules every 15
schedule ahead for 30
missed if not run within 45
success history lifetime 1440
failure history lifetime 1440
heartbeat taske */5 * * *

I am using Magento 1.7

Thanks everyone! This is pretty new to me

Here is my cron.php file -

require 'app/Mage.php';

```
if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

umask(0);

try {
    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}
```

Comment: Did you found solution ?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue cronjobs not working. I searched and found a solution that worked for me. My Magento is ver. 1.9.1 though.

http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob

I added the following line in cron.php

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

after the line

```
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, ‘win’) === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

Hope this helps someone who has same issue.

Comment: are you telling your cron job was working fine and aoe scheduler heartbeat was not found ?

Answer (score 1):

Most transactional emails are triggered synchronously during runtime through Magento’s events system. I can’t ask any follow up questions about your development environment, but are you sure that your [system cron is set up to trigger Magento’s cron service](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)? AOE Scheduler can generate the cron schedules but you still need the system cron to invoke Magento’s cron service.

> To execute all these configured tasks, the cron.php file located in
>   the Magento root will need to be run periodically, for example every
>   15 minutes. Basically, this script will check if it needs to run any
>   tasks, and if it needs to schedule any future tasks.

While setting up the system cron service is crucial for getting all of Magento’s scheduled tasks to run normally, and for testing purposes I would still recommend this, you can also [use AOE Scheduler to run specific jobs immediately from the Admin Panel](http://fbrnc.net/blog/2011/03/magento-cron-scheduler). Check out the screenshot in the linked article that shows the screen where you can do this. Simply select the job you need to run and choose “Run now” from the Actions box.

> You can also choose to run the task directly. Be careful with that, as
>   the execution might last longer than a few seconds or might depend on
>   some other command line environment settings. For testing small tasks
>   this might still be a comfortable option.

Comment: Thank you @fantasticrice, that helps! I do have a crop.php file - I've pasted the code above -  I don't see anything that would tell it to run every 15 min (or any other time)

Comment: @ClaireKooperman - cron.php is Magento’s launcher for running the cron service. You can think of it like index.php is for the web frontend. It is confusing because Magento’s cron services won’t run on their own without being called by a [system cron service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or equivalent in your environment. Check out that Magento wiki article I linked in my original answer (which is where I quoted from) to see more info about setting that up in whatever is your local environment. Let me know if you are still unclear after that.

Comment: for me cron is working fine, but getting message : `heartbeat not found` ? can you please help.